# Configure rails to use full `object_name`_id parameter on all routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When creating routes in rails, the `resources` method makes routes such as the following

```
resources :objects

# => GET '/objects/:id'
# etc...
```

However when nesting routes inside of `resources` the `id` parameter applies to the nested resource, as such

```
resources :objects do
  resources :nested_objects
end

# => GET '/objects/:object_id/nested_objects/:id'
```

What I would prefer is for resources to never use the `param[:id]`, but instead to always use the full `param[:object_id]`, so I can encapsulate similar behavior when nesting controllers.

Is there a config for this? It seems like very poor design for the convenience of writing `id` instead of `object_name_id` every once in a while

Answer (score 1):

the `params[:id]` always points to the id of the current resource. Thats just the convention.
You can override this convention in your `routes.rb` like this:

```
resources :objects do
  resources :nested_objects, param: :nested_object_id
end
```

> It seems like very poor design for the convenience of writing id
>   instead of object_name_id

I'd argue that though

Comment: I'm interested to hear your argument. The reason I don't like i is because it doesn't seem like it follows rails' POLS